# How does calculating the Loss work with multiple Outputs in Regression with a NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, loss

I set up a NN with 10 Output values/nodes. Some of them are coordinates, angles and distances.

After lots of training my train and test loss gets very good. (~0.05)
But after testing the values visually the results aren't that good. (some are, but not all)

My questions are:

1. Do I need a loss function that calculates a loss value for each value?
   I noticed that the sum the values of my label and the sum of my pred values are very similar.
2. Would reducing the dimensions of my NN output be a solution for this? (Instead of 10 outputs only 6)

For loss calculation this code is used:

```
def get_loss(pred, label, end_points):
   hubers = tf.compat.v1.losses.huber_loss(label, pred)
   regression_loss = tf.compat.v1.reduce_mean(hubers)
   tf.compat.v1.summary.scalar('regression loss', regression_loss)
   tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection('losses', regression_loss)
return regression_loss
```

Thank you for your time. :)

Edit:

Thank you for your response. :) I am only measuring the error visually, because there infinity right solutions. I'm trying to detect specific points on an object.

Because I only have a small dataset (~500 sets) i used to rotate the data around the z axis in 15 degree steps to get more data. Before increasing the data on this way, best loss was ~0.2.

My input label is a 10*1 vector and it looks like this:

```
[distance,X,Y,Z,alpha,beta,gamma,deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ]


5.720092519071295900e-02
1.006699085235540636e-03
8.009913066864016162e-02
1.114500999450683594e+00
-3.119294947657255790e+00
4.009960331703191737e-03
-2.526702780658843128e+00
-1.214617763502171266e-01
-1.560672931229585836e-01
8.294558525085449219e-02
```

While my pred looks like this:

```
4.625578597187995911e-02
-4.372183978557586670e-02
1.622541248798370361e-02
1.086338281631469727e+00
-3.110351085662841797e+00
7.853045314550399780e-02
-2.459422111511230469e+00
-4.620660468935966492e-02
-5.462351441383361816e-02
7.349613308906555176e-02
```

[Picture of my actual loss function (green is train loss; red is test loss)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0QrL.png)

I am not scaling the values at all.

Comment: See, you need to add more info like code and data for people to understand and debug out the solution for you, It's hard to guess without knowing what kind of data you're working with etc.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the weights is not depends on the sum of the predictions of outputs, it depends on the sum of the gradient of all 10  loss functions.

Even if your training and validation error seems good while training, there may still a high error for your unscaled data. I don't know how you measured the test error. Just as a reminder, MSE should be measured between the inverse scaled predicted value and real test values. Be sure to inverse scaling your predictions.

Attending specific loss function for labels may give good results depends on the target data distribution and contribution to your problem. And reducing the dimension of output strategy is also depends on the contribution of the discarded label to learning progress.